# Using 2 Python Arrays

Tags: python, arrays

I have two, 2 Dimensional arrays that are both the same size that have different values in each of them. I want to be able to find a value in one of the arrays, say all of the 2s, and where there are all 2s, fill with whatever value is in the same spot in the other array. How would you do that in Python?

Comment: This is way too broad, what have you tried?

Comment: You have to provide some code, and at least the 2 2D arrays (input and desired output)

Comment: If I have an array of [ [1 2 2], [3 4 2], [6 2 4] ] and another array of [ [.02 .91 .65], [.30 .01 .54], [.06 .31 .81] ], I want to be able to replace all of the 2s in the first array with the values in the second array that are in the same spot. For example, I would want the first 2 in the first array to have a value of .91

Comment: 2D arrays can be implemented in different ways (to name a few, list of lists, the `array` module, the `numpy` module). If you want some help, could you please specify what you've already done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `numpy`, you could try this:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[11,12,13],[21,22,23],[31,32,33]])
B = np.array([[ 1, 2, 3],[ 2, 1, 3],[ 1, 3, 2]])
B[B==2] = A[B==2]
```

Here, `B==2` creates a boolean matrix with a `True` for each cell where there is a `2` in `B`. Now, `B[B==2]` gets all those cells from `B` and sets them to whatever is there in `A` with `A[B==2]`.

Afterwards, each `2` in `B` is replaced with the corresponding value from `A`:

```
[[ 1 12  3]
 [21  1  3]
 [ 1  3 33]]
```